# TFS 2010: Is it possible to use a list of key value pairs in the ProcessParameterMetadataCollection?

Tags: c#, tfs, workflow, build-process

I am trying to configure my TFS Workflow with the `ProcessParameterMetadataCollection`. I need a list of key value pairs. 
Something like:

[image]

Then I want to iterate through the collection and invoke a separate workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but a little cumbersome.

In a nutshell, you would need to:

1. Create a UITypeEditor capable of editing Dictionaries;
2. Deploy your UITypeEditor (adding its assembly to source control and configuring the Build Controller to download that assembly);
3. Create an Argument in your build process template of type Dictionary<string,string>;
4. Modify the Metadata argument to add a new entry representing the argument you created in step #3, configuring the Editor field with the UITypeEditor you created in step #1.
5. Modify your workflow to iterate over your dictionary as needed, using e.g. a For activity.

The hardest thing would be to create your Dictionary editor. Luckily it seems there is a good starting point: http://gendictedit.codeplex.com/